# BehaviorSubject in angular returning null null

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I am using BehaviorSubject to store some form data info, but for some  reason, the info returned by BehaviorSubject is null.
myService.ts

```js
 taskData$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});
```

task.create.component.html which uses a custom library

```html
<sc-form-wrapper>
            <div class="button-wrap">
                <div class="input-text-container">                   
                    <sc-text-input id="taskName" (onFocusout)="getTaskName($event)"
                                    [required]="true"                                    
                                    label="Task Name"
                                    size="md">
                    </sc-text-input>                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="">Task Colors</div>
            <div *ngFor="let code of taskdata; let i = index" class="radio-container">
                <ng-container>
                    <div class="radio-task-list">
                        <input id="{{ 'radio-' + i }}" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio" (change)="selectTaskCode($event,code)">
                        <label for="{{ 'radio-' + i }}" class="radio-custom-label tag-color-{{i}}"></label>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
        </sc-form-wrapper>
```

task.create.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SetTask } from '../../models/task.model';
import { TaskSetCode } from '../../models/task-set-code.model';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from '../../services/error-handler.service';
import { TaskListService } from '../../services/task-list.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-create',
  templateUrl: './task-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-create.component.css']
})
export class TaskCreateComponent implements OnInit {
    private destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();  
    setTask: SetTask;
    selectedTaskName: any;
    selectedTaskCode: any;
    setTaskData: any;    
    disableCreateButton: boolean = true;
    taskSetCode: TaskSetCode = new TaskSetCode();
    selectedTaskData: any;


    constructor(   
        private errorHandlerService: ErrorHandlerService,
        private taskService: TaskListService,
        private router: Router,
        private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setTask = {
            taskName: "",
            taskCode: "",
            createdBy: ""
        };
       this.createButtonDisable();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next(true);
        this.destroy$.complete();        
    }


    //Getting the task name
    getTaskName(event) {
        Object.defineProperty(this.setTask, event.controlName, { value: event.value });
        this.selectedTaskName = this.setTask.taskName;
        if (event.controlName === "taskName" && event.value !== undefined)  {
            this.disableCreateButton = false;
        } else {
            this.disableCreateButton = true;
        }
        this.createButtonDisable();
        const setTaskData: SetTag = {
            taskName: this.selectedTaskTaskName,
            taskCode: this.selectedTaskCode,
        };   
       this.createButtonDisable();
    }

    //Getting the selected task code
    selectTaskCode(e, Code: string) {
        this.selectedTaskCode = code;
        const setTaskData: SetTag = {
            taskName: this.selectedTaskTaskName,
            taskCode: this.selectedTaskCode,
        };
        this.setTaskData = setTaskData;
        if (this.selectedTaskCode == '' && this.selectedTaskName == '' ) {
            this.disableCreateButton = true;
        } else {
            this.disableCreateButton = false;
        }
        this.createButtonDisable();
               
    }

    
    createButtonDisable() {           
        if (this.setTaskData !== undefined) {          
            this.taskService.taskData$.next(this.setTaskData);
        }
    }

 }
```

Trying to subscribe the data in task-list.component and trying to get the data, but getting null value

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TaskListService } from '../../services/task-list.service';
import { TaskCreateComponent } from '../task-create/task-create.component';
import { ModalService } from 'model-components';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-list',
  templateUrl: './task-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-list.component.css']
})
export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit {    
    private destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

    taskData: any;

    constructor(
        public taskService: TaskListService       
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {   
       
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next(true);
        this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
    }
    createTask(): void {

        const ref = this.modalService.openModal('Create Task', TaskCreateComponent,
            {                
                cancelText: 'Cancel',
                submitText: 'Create'

            }
        );

        const modalCompInstance: any = ref.componentInstance;
        modalCompInstance.modalEvent.subscribe((event) => {
            const type = event.type;

            if (type !== 'submit') {
                ref.close();
                return;
            }
            else {
                this.saveTag();                
                ref.close();
            }
        });
    }

    saveTask() {
        
        this.taskService.taskData$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
            .subscribe((tasks: any) => {                
                this.taskData = tasks;
            });
    }
}
```

Can you please point out the issue or guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `saveTask` in your `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook within your `TaskListComponent`

```js
ngOnInit() {
 this.saveTask();
}
```

`ngOnInit` will listen for any changes emitted by your special observable `taskData$`

Also, it is a good practice to have functions within your service to handle your subject, you want only your service `next`ing the values, with this approach, it is also easier for testing purposes

```js
export class YourService {
  private theSubject = new BehaviorSubject({});

  getTasks(): Observable<any> {
    return this.theSubject.asObservable();
  }

  nextMyValue(value: any): void {
    this.theSubject.next(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding  this.saveTask(); in ngOnInit, but still i am getting the this.taskData ={}. I wanted to get this as {taskName: "Task1", taskCode: "NEW"}. Somehow the   this.taskService.taskData$.next(this.setTaskData); is not updating the value.

Comment: how are you providing your service? could you recreate this on Stackblitz?

Comment: i just tried recreating this in StackBittz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkwzm2?file=src/app/task-list/task-list.component.s. please check there. thanks

Comment: I am using a custom library model popup and on closing on the submit button i was trying to get the form values there for saving the data